Why is the tween transition immediate instead of being progressive?
I am doing a mini-project with libGDX and implementing the universal-tween-engine library.
The problem is that when I want to make the transition of the opacity from 0 to 1 of a Sprite, the transition is practically imperceptible. The reason however that I know that the Tween.set method works is because when I commented the line Tween.to..., and opened the application again, the sprite appeared for a very brief moment to suddenly become invisible as it should be (I don't know if that's a bug or if that's how it should work).
One way to solve it was to directly set the initial value of the splash sprite with splash.setAlpha(0) but I don't think it is the most appropriate solution.
public class Splash implements Screen {
    
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Sprite splash;
    private TweenManager tweenManager;
    
    @Override
    public void show() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        
        tweenManager = new TweenManager();
        Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());
        
        
        Texture splashTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/splash-image.jpg"));    

        splash = new Sprite(splashTexture);
        splash.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        
        Tween.set(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0).start(tweenManager);
        Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 3).target(1).start(tweenManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        tweenManager.update(delta);
        
        batch.begin();
        splash.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    // ...

This is my SpriteAccesor class:
package com.mygdx.game.tween;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;

import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenAccessor;

public class SpriteAccessor implements TweenAccessor<Sprite>{
    public static final int ALPHA = 0;

    @Override
    public int getValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {
        switch(tweenType) {
        case ALPHA:
            returnValues[0] = target.getColor().a;
            return 1;
        default:
            assert false;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
        switch(tweenType) {
        case ALPHA:
            target.setColor(target.getColor().r, target.getColor().g, target.getColor().b, newValues[0]);
            break;
        default:
            assert false;
        }
    }

}


I don't know the LibGDX API directly but for me it look like a nonsense starting tween twice: on line 19. and 20.

I was following a tutorial and in theory what the "Tween.set" method should do (as far as I understood) is set the initial value of a property, but for some reason it doesn't work for me (At about minute 11 he talks about it: https://youtu.be/2PqwxYVlivA?list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0JOwHiH1TntAdq-UDPnC2L&t=672)

Maybe there's something wrong with your SpriteAccessor class?
